# Blank admin page on Magento 2.3.0 CE in localhost

Tags: javascript, php, magento, xampp, magento2

I have installed Magento 2.3 on my local-machine, installation goes fine. I can access my store at `localhost/magento`. I tried to access my admin page `localhost/magento/admin_pogi` but it gives me a blank page and redirected to the url `http://localhost/magento/admin_pogi/admin/index/index/key/a062e79f617010c42b07d662103d5142cd9bbe86314fb54da3e4cb5542b11eee/`.

What I have tried so far is to enable development mode, and I see this error on my admin page:

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\ValidatorException): Invalid 
template file: 'C:/xampp/htdocs/magento/vendor/magento/module- backend/view/adminhtml/templates/page/js/require_js.phtml' in module: 
'Magento_Backend' block's name: 'require.js'

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\ValidatorException): Invalid template file: 'C:/xampp/htdocs/magento/vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/page/js/require_js.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Backend' block's name: 'require.js'
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\Template.php(301): 
Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('C:/xampp/htdocs...')
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock.php(668): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml()#2 
C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\View\Result\Page.php(249): 
Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml()
#3 
C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\View\Result\Layout.php(171): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page->render(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\generated\code\Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page\Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\App\Http.php(139): Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\generated\code\Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#7 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\App\Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch()
#8 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))
#9 {main}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This would be a bug that addresses [this commit](https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/8110949e4dd4faa8d36b25ecfeb7779ebbac5741#diff-643a52d0419707fc6b1a9c95a9b5a632L131). Author changed `$path` to

```
$this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path)
```

which is simply calling `realpath()` on `$path` but that might change directory separators on the `$path` that previously were affected by

```
#/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template/File/Validator.php:114
$filename = str_replace('\\', '/', $filename);
```

On a Windows OS this will revert changes of above `str_replace` so that a path like

```
D:/Magento2.3/vendor/magento
```

will be canonicalized to its Windows specific version:

```
D:\Magento2.3\vendor\magento
```

and this will not result in a successful comparison within `isPathInDirectories()` method of `Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\File\Validator` class:

```
foreach ($directories as $directory) {
    if (0 === strpos($realPath, $directory)) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

## Solution

Currently we can go for a dirty quick change in the above `foreach` loop so that we can run our magento with no further problems on this:

```
#/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template/File/Validator.php:139
foreach ($directories as $directory) {
    // Add this line
    $realDirectory = $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($directory);
    // and replace `$directory` with `$realDirectory`
    if (0 === strpos($realPath, $realDirectory)) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. So you mean that 2.3.0 is not a stable version? if yes, what is the version would you recommend for me? And sir, I have many questions about magento. Im new to magento. Can I ask more questions from you? If it is okay, where can I contact you? Thanks sir! You saved my whole day!!!!

Comment: You're welcome. v2.2.6 is probably a better choice for now. I'm new to v2 as well so I can't be a good hand in it.

Comment: 10 days, and they still haven't released any small incremental update, to fix this glaring bug. Quite sad...

Comment: @revo, can you provide the fix to override it in local?

Comment: @GhostCat I'm very glad to hear that!

Answer (score 4):

Step 01.
Go to this directory
C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\Template\File

Step 02.
Open file validator.php 
Comment line 139($realPath = $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path);) 
Add this code

`$realPath=str_replace('\\','/', $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path));`

And also some time admin page load but not load css So how to fix this issue

Step _01
Goto the this directory
App/etc/di.xml

step 02 
Find this line

```
<item name="view_preprocessed" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink</item>
```

Step 03
change this like below

```
<item name="view_preprocessed" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\copy</item>
```

And also some time the home page not load correctly so how can solve

Step 01
Go to the this directory 
var/cache

Step 02
Delete cache files and refresh your page

Comment: Admin page required more then few refreshes, but it finally started to work :D

Comment: That's Worked for me!

Answer (score 3):

This is Magento 2.3.0's core issue.
To fix this issue you have to change the code in the core file of Magento.

Go to path **/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template/File/Validator.php** In this file find:

```
$realPath = $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path);
```

Replace with:

```
$realPath = str_replace('\\', '/', $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path));
```