# Magento 2.3.2 on Windows 10 XAMPP - distorted backend

Tags: php, magento

I have installed Magento 2.3.2 on localhost (Win10/XAMPP) successfully but I had blank admin page and distorted front-end.

Thankfully, following question [Blank admin page after installing Magento 2.3 on Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53565012/blank-admin-page-after-installing-magento-2-3-on-windows-10) and few other threads I have restored front-end, but back-end is still distorted.

[image]

As I understand it, it was an issue with wrong path which I've updated as suggested and now I can login to back-end but it is still distorted.

[image]

Comment: Can you edit the question with a clear question for us? Thanks.

Comment: You will almost certainly find the files don't exist, the error you're getting is a red herring. Have a look here and at my answer which provides an explanation and a means of proving the files don't actually exist: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/152625/magento2-css-was-blocked-due-to-mime-type-mismatch-x-content-type-options-nosn

Comment: @PedroKTFC I agree it's a 404, I am trying to figure out why it is there! Any ideas?

Comment: This explains how I build magento and get all the files created: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56430125/magento-2-install-windows-admin-broken-links/56439184#56439184

Answer (score 0):

You have to redeploy static contents by running static content deploy command:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f // -f to force deploy
```

Don't forget to **clear cache,** after.

Comment: well it gave me this [In File.php line 151:

  The contents from the "Q:/xampp/htdocs/magento/pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/css/styles.css" file can'
  t be read. Warning!file_get_contents(Q:/xampp/htdocs/magento/pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/css/styles.css): failed to open stream: No such file or directory] any idea how we can get this working. Thanks

Comment: can you include the line of codes wherein you applied the fix you found in the other post

Comment: permissions problem?