# magento 2.3 After install blank screen

Tags: magento, magento2, magento-2.3

[image: Sceen Shot].

After install with no error , admin blank screen but it gives error on console on browser.

[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: Here is the solution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53551878/blank-admin-page-on-magento-2-3-0-ce-in-localhost

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: First solution there worked for me.
[After installing magento 2.3 admin login page cant open properly](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/252069/after-installing-magento-2-3-admin-login-page-cant-open-properly)

Answer (score 2):

Please follow instructions below. I hope it will resolve your issue.

Just go to `vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template/File/Validator.php` and find function **function isPathInDirectories** line 138.

Replace:

```
$realPath = $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path);
        foreach ($directories as $directory) {
            if (0 === strpos($realPath, $directory)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
```

With:

```
$realPath = $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path);
        foreach ($directories as $directory) {
            $directory = $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path);  //Add this line.
            if (0 === strpos($realPath, $directory)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing the same issue while installing Magento 2.3.3 in my localhost - XAMPP Server. It's successfully installed, but when I opening the admin panel, it appeared a blank screen like the below image. [Admin Panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhWy3.jpg)

The Solution is:

After that, I changed the code like below.

Go to this Path: **..\vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\Template\File** then Open this file **Validator.php**

Then Search this line **$realPath = $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path);**

Replace to **$realPath = str_replace('\', '/', $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path));**

[Image for reference to change the Validator.php file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bb8S.jpg)

Now Admin Panel will appear successfully.

Admin Panel appeared, but the issue is Magento logo does not appear on the login screen. After logging the admin [Admin Panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdIuD.jpg), Icons don't appear on the dashboard also its continuously loading like the below images [Icon Don't Appear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzlR7.jpg)

The solution is:

Go to this Path: **..\app\etc** then Open this file **di.xml**

Then search this line **Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink**

To Replace the line **Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy**

[Check this image for replacing the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/feeMM.jpg) & [Make sure the code should come like this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxG1f.jpg)

Now Go to the Admin Panel and Refresh the page. It's Successfully working without issues. All icons have appeared also Logo is appeared.

[Admin Panel Sucess image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4j83V.jpg)

Now Go to Client Area, if you update sample content, the page looks like this image [Client Page with Sample Content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOBiF.jpg). Otherwise, it will appear like "CMS homepage content goes here".

Everything is working good.

I hope it will use to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

In lib\internal\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\File\Validator.php

Replace

```
$realPath = $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path);
```

With

```
$realPath = str_replace("\\", "/", $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path) );`
```

Then Run this in your terminal:

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```