# Mangeto admin url shows only blank page

Tags: magento, magento-2.3

I am new in Magento and installed mangento 2.3.1. Now after successful installation, when I access admin url which is :

http://localhost/mangento2/admin

it redirects me to below page and shows only grey screen :

http://localhost/magento2/admin/admin/index/index/key/7c152a33f0804b87b96cde0ac216340d04352b021ce4fd833ecf998d180e8823/

Screen : 
[image]

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Blank admin page on Magento 2.3.0 CE in localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53551878/blank-admin-page-on-magento-2-3-0-ce-in-localhost)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is a problem that other people also experienced with 2.2.7 (and 2.3.1).

You can see the solution [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/252188/magento-2-2-7-admin-panel-blank-page).

You can also see if there is an official patch [here](https://magento.com/security/patches).